# Failing to fetch package from cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org in docker buid

Tags: docker, debian

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends --force-yes --fix-missing\
    curl \
    git \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    maven \
    python2.7 python2.7-setuptools \
    python3 python3-setuptools \
    r-base \
    r-base-core && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

On building this Dokerfile, I got error:

> W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.
>   E: Failed to fetch http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libpsl/libpsl5_0.17.0-3_amd64.deb  Connection failed
>   E: Failed to fetch http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/j/jbigkit/libjbig0_2.1-3.1+b2_amd64.deb  Connection failed
>   E: Failed to fetch http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxmu/libxmuu1_1.1.2-2_amd64.deb  Connection failed
>   E: Failed to fetch http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/plexus-cli/libplexus-cli-java_1.2-5_all.deb  Connection failed
>   E: Aborting install.

Comment: From error, it seems some internet connectivity issue. I tried the same `dockerfile` at my end and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source list, I guess this related to different site visit to `deb.debian.org`:

```
$ docker run --rm -it debian:stretch cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20190708T033000Z stretch main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20190708T033000Z stretch/updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20190708T033000Z stretch-updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
```

Move your steps to http://deb.debian.org/, you can see this:

> The server deb.debian.org does not have packages itself, but the name has SRV records in DNS that let apt in stretch and later find places.

So I guess, sometimes it will redirect you to one mirror which may not very situable for you because of your local network limit. As a result, I suggest you directly use a suitable `sources.list` to replace the original one in image, all availables see [all the Debian mirrors](https://www.debian.org/mirror/sponsors.html), you can choose one which in your country.

Answer (score 2):

I used [debian mirrors](https://www.debian.org/mirror/sponsors.html) from @atline's answer and it worked for me.

Just want to add an example. For India, I added below step in Dockerfile

```
RUN echo \
   'deb http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/debian/ stretch main\n \
    deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main\n \
    deb http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/debian/ stretch-updates main\n' \
    > /etc/apt/sources.list
```